# HTML - Removing unwanted space to the right of text inside table cell / table header

Tags: html, css

I have a table cell defined in the following fashion that is producing wanted space to the right of the inner text of the td or th.

```
<td>
     <nobr>
         <span>Text</span>
     </nobr>
</td>
```

My table header is also defined similar to the above code.

```
<th>
     <nobr>
         <span>Header</span>
     </nobr>
</th>
```

How do I get my table upon rendering to not add extra space to the right of the text content after all table data is fetched?

Comment: Have you tried changing the width of your `<td>` elements?

Comment: try to put ur code in fiddle or codepen for better clarity

Comment: I just found my issue, I had some javascript that I forgot to remove that interfered with my width calculations.  My width is calculated on the PHP side with max-with: and min-width: in css.  So by removing the javascript code to calculate width for fixed header I was able to resolve it.  Thank you for the quick reply.

Comment: Note that `<nobr>` is a non standard element and should be avoided, use `white-space: nowrap` instead (on the `span` in this case)

Comment: Please provide enough code for the finding errors.